# Packet Switching vs Packet Routing

Tags: tcp, ip

The TCP/IP protocol suite makes use of [packet switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) to exchange data between end-systems. I would like to know though why do we call it so? Why choosing the term 'switching' instead of 'routing' which sounds to me more convenient in this context since the term 'packet switching' defines a communication method between two end-systems and not just adjacent nodes (based on the role each of the router and the switch plays in computer networks)?

Comment: Actually it doesn't. It uses routing. Switching happens at the device layer, level 2 or below. Off topic.

Comment: This does not answer my question though! Why choosing the term switching then ?

Answer (score 1):

The name is more to do with the history of evolution of communications.

**Message Switching** is used in Telegraph Networks.

Later, Telephone Networks were built on top of Telegraph Networks and unlike the concept of entire Messages "Switching" from one location to location, Telephones uses the concept of Bandwidth Pre-allocation by establishing a dedicated Circuit, and this is called as **Circuit Switching**.

In early days, telephone operators manually established the telephone connections by plugging the cables, so the name "switching" still made sense and it continued to be used.

Later came the Computer Networks, which followed the same legacy and were built on top of Telephone Networks. Unlike Bandwidth Pre-allocation in Telephone Networks(which is very inefficient), Computer Networks uses bursts of messages called Packets, and the communication of Packets over Telephone Networks were called as **Packet Switching**.

You see, the name followed the legacy of previous generation communication technologies.